# how to call a different js file output to another js file by using onclick button in react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

the given are the files i created as js file.....clicking button in the same file which I commented the 
button tag in output.js that is working fine and if i change the button in different page that is the confusion

output.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'



class Threed extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super() 
        this.state ={show:false}
    }
    threedModal(){
        this.setState({show:!this.state.show})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/*<Button onClick= {() => {this.threedModal()}}>
                    rajesh
        </Button>*/}
                <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={() => this.handleModal()}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>MY popup</Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>Rajesh modal done</Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer><Button onClick= {() => {this.handleModal()}}> close </Button></Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Threed
```

home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import threed from './output.js'


class Threed extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super() 
        this.state ={show:false}
    }
    threedModal(){
        this.setState({show:!this.state.show})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Button onClick= {() => {this.threedModal()}}>
                    rajesh
        </Button>
           </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Threed
```

I want to show while clicking home.js button and show the modal popup window......
here my confusion is how to get that fuction by clicking button of Home.js

Comment: You can conditionally return the modal. Only return the modal when `show` is true, and always return the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please forward the value to modal.

**Home.js**

```js
import Threed from './output.js'
class Home extends Component {

...
< Threed show={this.state.show} />
```

**Threed.js**

```js
 <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={() => this.handleModal()}>
```